# Laravel / Blade: tabs/spaces not included properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**The issue:**

Tabs are not being processed properly when including templates using Blade (in a Laravel app) after viewing the page source code in the browser

**default.blade.php:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        @include('includes.head')
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**head.blade.php:**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="Test" content="">
```

**What it looks like when viewing source on the browser:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="Test" content="">
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the last two meta tags are for some reason being tabbed backwards instead of aligning with the first meta tag. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding @Andrei Lupuleasa answer, blade consider indentation from your master layout. so it is taking indentation from master.blade.php. please put 2 tab space in your head.blade.php.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Where do I put it? Also do you mean 2 "tabs" or 2 "spaces" ?

Comment: in your head.blade.php just put tabs 2 times before each lines.

Comment: Wait each line? I put it at the top of the file and it seems to works. Are you sure I need to do it for each line?

Answer (score 1):

Put tabs in your `head.blade.php`.

```
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="Test" content="">
```

First line is indented ok because it uses the indentation from `default.blade.php`, the tabs before `@include...`

From what I see there is also a problem with `blade` indentation:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/problem-with-indentation-in-blade-views

So i suggest to remove the indentation from layout:

```
<html>
    <head>
@include('includes.head')
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is not pretty but it will solve your problem.

Comment: Have you tested it @Andrei Lupuleasa?

Comment: Everything still gets misaligned.